# How to remove directory string from a file name in c#

Tags: c#, string, file, listbox, directory

This is my code

```
string[] games = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.exe");            
listBox1.Items.AddRange(games);
```

Right now it prints out an entire directory as a string. I want to get only the file name, so the last part of the directory. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason I can't. Sorry if I sound really dumb. Do I need to add a reference or is there a certain class I need to import?

edit: nvm, got it.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `FileInfo` Class to get that information:

```
string[] games = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.exe")
                          .Select(x => new FileInfo(x).Name)
                          .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this way

```
string[] games = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.exe");
foreach (var g in games)
{
   listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(g));
}
```

Comment: I can't do the 2nd one because the compiler cannot convert a list string to the listbox

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
file_name = Path.GetFileName (your path);
```

GetFileName will retrun the file name from the path string

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(...)`. Please read the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) also.